# Discord.js const guild = member.guild;

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello Programmers I Have Problem With Discord.js I Made Bot Which Is Says Hello @user But It Doesn't Work

Here Is My Code:

> Javascript

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const TOKEN = "private";
const PREFIX = "!";
const newUser = new Discord.Collection();
const talkedRecently = new Set();
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var fortunes = 
[
"Yes",
"No",
"Maybe",
"IDK"
];
bot.on("ready", () => {
});

        client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
            const guild = member.guild;
            newUsers.set(member.id, member.user);

            if (newUsers.size > 0) {
              const defaultChannel = guild.channels.find(c=> c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"));
              const userlist = newUsers.map(u => u.toString()).join(" ");
              defaultChannel.send("Hello Creativistian!\n" + userlist);
              newUsers.clear();
            }
          });
    });

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Does Anyone Know How To Fix It

Answer (score 4):

Replace `client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {` with this:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
```

Note: as @Noobly387 said, you have an extra `});`, on line 15, please remove that.

***Cheers***

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem remove `});` on line 15 just after `bot.on("ready", () => {`.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please provide more information on your issue.

Although, your error is that you have an extra unnecessary `});`.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, be sure to state your question in the title so people can help you easier.

On line 15, you have an extra `});` below your `bot.on("ready", () => {` code. This breaks the code because by ending the bot.on line, the rest of the code below will not work since it becomes just regular functions.

Also, as a side note, I would recommend for you to make your arrays single line if they are small (such as your fortunes array) and also don't space out your code too much or you won't be able to see the small problems such as the one that broke your code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {`  with this :

`bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {`

PS: on line 15 you have an extra unnecessary `});`

Answer (score 0):

Use that with **ALL THE INTENTS ON**.

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
// Code..
});
```

That work in discord.jsv12, to install type this command
`npm install discord.js@v12`